# Jquery Data Table - No data available in table

Tags: c#, html, jquery, datatables

I have developed an application using .net core. One of my requirements is datatables. In my controller I am calling a REST Api service and returning a Json result. The view is pretty straight forward in that of my html table and the AJAX call to the controller for data. Upon execution of the application my datatable shows up with **'No data available in table'**

```
                    <table id="datatable">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th class="table-column-pr-0 sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="" style="width: 44px;">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input id="datatableCheckAll" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="datatableCheckAll"></label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="table-column-pl-0 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 299px;">UserID</th>
                            <th class="table-column-pl-0 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 299px;">UserName</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 195px;">DepartmentID</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>


                    </tbody>
                   </table>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ApplicationUsers/LoadData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {  
                OnSuccess(response);
            },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
    });


    // INITIALIZATION OF DATATABLES
    // =======================================================
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.noConflict();
        $('#datatable').DataTable(
            {
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                bLengthChange: true,
                lengthMenu: [[5, 10, -1], [5, 10, "All"]],
                bFilter: true,
                bSort: true,
                bPaginate: true,
                searching: false,
                data: response,
                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'userID', "defaultContent": "", },
                    { 'data': 'userName', "defaultContent": "", },
                    { 'data': 'departmentID', "defaultContent": "", }]
            });
    };
 </script>








    public class ApplicationUsersController : Controller
    {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadData()
    {
        var data = ClaimsService.GetUsers();
        return Json(new { data = data});
    }
    }
```

**JSON DATA**

```
{"data":{"result":[{"userID":322,"userName":"Ashnee","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Ashnee Pillay                                     ","emailAddress":"Ashnee@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":323,"userName":"BalanC","departmentID":15,"branchID":5,"name":"Balan Chetty                                      ","emailAddress":"BalanC@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":328,"userName":"BrettL","departmentID":1,"branchID":1,"name":"Brett Lange                                       ","emailAddress":"BrettL@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":334,"userName":"CoenieB","departmentID":14,"branchID":4,"name":"Coenie De Beer                                    ","emailAddress":"CoenieB@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":337,"userName":"TraceyA","departmentID":61,"branchID":30,"name":"Tracey De Andrade                            ","emailAddress":"TraceyA@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":350,"userName":"HenryB","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Henry Barber                                      ","emailAddress":"HenryB@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":351,"userName":"HowardG","departmentID":6,"branchID":1,"name":"Howard Gains                                      ","emailAddress":"HowardG@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":354,"userName":"IreneK","departmentID":17,"branchID":7,"name":"Irene Koegelenberg                                ","emailAddress":"IreneK@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":356,"userName":"JayM","departmentID":2,"branchID":1,"name":"Jay Mahillal                                      ","emailAddress":"JayM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":359,"userName":"TheshniR","departmentID":4,"branchID":1,"name":"Theshni Reddy                               ","emailAddress":"TheshniR@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":363,"userName":"Mariov","departmentID":15,"branchID":5,"name":"Mario Vincent                                     ","emailAddress":"mariov@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":366,"userName":"Rehana","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Rehana Adams                                      ","emailAddress":"Rehana@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":368,"userName":"FrancoisC","departmentID":19,"branchID":9,"name":"Francois Cloete                                   ","emailAddress":"FrancoisC@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":369,"userName":"CharneW","departmentID":22,"branchID":10,"name":"Charne Wagner                                     ","emailAddress":"CharneW@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":372,"userName":"Rajeshree","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Rajeshree Singh                                   ","emailAddress":"Rajeshree@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":377,"userName":"SamanthaM","departmentID":2,"branchID":1,"name":"Samantha Murugan                                  ","emailAddress":"SamanthaM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":381,"userName":"SueP","departmentID":2,"branchID":1,"name":"Sue Pillay                                        ","emailAddress":"SueP@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":382,"userName":"Sunitha","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Sunitha Kandhai                                   ","emailAddress":"Sunitha@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":385,"userName":"TraceyL","departmentID":20,"branchID":12,"name":"Tracey Lambooy                                    ","emailAddress":"TraceyL@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":387,"userName":"Vinola","departmentID":80,"branchID":30,"name":"Vinola Kalideen                                   ","emailAddress":"Vinola@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":397,"userName":"MarioL","departmentID":5,"branchID":1,"name":"Mario Luis","emailAddress":"MarioL@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":403,"userName":"SteveJ","departmentID":9,"branchID":14,"name":"Steve Jarman","emailAddress":"SteveJ@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":404,"userName":"MarkN","departmentID":18,"branchID":1,"name":"Mark Naicker","emailAddress":"MarkN@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":406,"userName":"MosesQ","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"MosesQwabe","emailAddress":"MosesQ@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":407,"userName":"Evonn","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Evonn Naicker","emailAddress":"Evonn@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":417,"userName":"Brandon","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Brandon Booysen","emailAddress":"BrandonBO@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":419,"userName":"SifisoD","departmentID":9,"branchID":14,"name":"Sifiso Dlamini","emailAddress":"SifisoD@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":423,"userName":"Jnb.Workshop","departmentID":9,"branchID":14,"name":"Jnb.Workshop","emailAddress":"Jnb.Workshop@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":425,"userName":"PrenishaS","departmentID":15,"branchID":5,"name":"Prenisha Sami","emailAddress":"Prenishas@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":426,"userName":"Pzb.Operations","departmentID":20,"branchID":12,"name":"Gift Kunene","emailAddress":"Pzb.Operations@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":427,"userName":"SalomeM","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Salome Mokwele","emailAddress":"SalomeM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":431,"userName":"GeorgeH","departmentID":12,"branchID":3,"name":"George Horn","emailAddress":"GeorgeH@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":434,"userName":"NadineF","departmentID":22,"branchID":10,"name":"Nadine Feldtmann","emailAddress":"NadineF@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":435,"userName":"ThiroshanN","departmentID":2,"branchID":1,"name":"Thiroshan Naicker","emailAddress":"ThiroshanN@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":442,"userName":"GeneN","departmentID":14,"branchID":4,"name":"Gene Naidoo","emailAddress":"GeneN@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":444,"userName":"Jnb.Boardroom","departmentID":1,"branchID":1,"name":"Jnb.Boardroom","emailAddress":"Jnb.Boardroom@Tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":447,"userName":"Mariob","departmentID":65,"branchID":37,"name":"Mario Botha","emailAddress":"Mariob@tritonfleet.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":449,"userName":"KureshaM","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Kuresha Moodley","emailAddress":"KureshaM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":453,"userName":"SeanR","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Sean Raidoo","emailAddress":"SeanR@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":459,"userName":"SalonaB","departmentID":3,"branchID":1,"name":"Salona Balram","emailAddress":"SalonaB@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":460,"userName":"JohannesS","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Johannes Van Staden","emailAddress":"JohannesS@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":463,"userName":"Dannyg","departmentID":15,"branchID":5,"name":"Danny Govender","emailAddress":"dannyg@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":466,"userName":"Shaneilr","departmentID":5,"branchID":1,"name":"Shaneil","emailAddress":"shaneilr@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":468,"userName":"BlessingM","departmentID":19,"branchID":9,"name":"Blessing Mlimi","emailAddress":"BlessingM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":477,"userName":"EnvorS","departmentID":13,"branchID":2,"name":"Envor Swart","emailAddress":" envors@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":481,"userName":"FritzB","departmentID":59,"branchID":25,"name":"Fritz Beudeker","emailAddress":"FritzB@tritonscs.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":483,"userName":"JuanP","departmentID":6,"branchID":1,"name":"Juan Potgieter","emailAddress":"JuanP@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":484,"userName":"NonhlanhlaMn","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Nonhlanhla Mnguni ","emailAddress":"NonhlanhlaM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":488,"userName":"WinnieM","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Winnie Mbongo","emailAddress":"WinnieM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":492,"userName":"JaendreS","departmentID":16,"branchID":6,"name":"Jaendre Serfontein","emailAddress":"JaendreS@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":497,"userName":"TshepoM","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Tshepo Mbele","emailAddress":"TshepoM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":498,"userName":"ItumelengL","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Itumeleng Leso","emailAddress":"ItumelengL@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":499,"userName":"Raynoldn","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Raynold Ngwane","emailAddress":"Raynoldn@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":504,"userName":"JarredM","departmentID":58,"branchID":24,"name":"Jarred Metzler","emailAddress":"JarredM@tritonscs.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":511,"userName":"MagdaG","departmentID":6,"branchID":1,"name":"Magda Greeff","emailAddress":"MagdaG@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":513,"userName":"WinstonB","departmentID":55,"branchID":28,"name":"Winston Blaine","emailAddress":"WinstonB@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":517,"userName":"ByronV","departmentID":27,"branchID":17,"name":"Byron Vickers ","emailAddress":"ByronV@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":521,"userName":"GertH","departmentID":61,"branchID":48,"name":"Gert Hael ","emailAddress":"GertH@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":523,"userName":"Nomsat","departmentID":88,"branchID":45,"name":"Nomsa Tshabalala","emailAddress":"NomsaT@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":527,"userName":"AndrewJ","departmentID":18,"branchID":8,"name":"Andrew Julius","emailAddress":"AndrewJ@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":528,"userName":"LeeH","departmentID":4,"branchID":1,"name":"Lee Hamberger","emailAddress":"LeeH@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":530,"userName":"KevinS","departmentID":4,"branchID":1,"name":"Kevin Smith","emailAddress":"KevinS@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":532,"userName":"PhumeleleM","departmentID":63,"branchID":33,"name":"Phumelele","emailAddress":"PhumeleleM@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":533,"userName":"GiftK","departmentID":20,"branchID":12,"name":"Gift Kunene","emailAddress":"Giftk@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":534,"userName":"MiguelF","departmentID":55,"branchID":28,"name":"Miguel","emailAddress":"MiguelF@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":535,"userName":"BilkisA","departmentID":2,"branchID":1,"name":"Bilkis Ahmod","emailAddress":"bilkisa@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":539,"userName":"HermanK","departmentID":24,"branchID":15,"name":"Herman Kleynhans","emailAddress":"HermanK@tritonexpress.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":543,"userName":"SomP","departmentID":58,"branchID":24,"name":"Som Pillay","emailAddress":"SomP@tritonscs.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"userID":544,"userName":"AndriesG","departmentID":73,"branchID":42,"name":"Andries Greyling","emailAddress":"AndriesG@tritonscs.co.za","archive_User":"0","managerID":0,"isHeadOffice":0,"statusID":1,"statusDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}],"id":1601,"exception":null,"status":5,"isCanceled":false,"isCompleted":true,"isCompletedSuccessfully":true,"creationOptions":0,"asyncState":null,"isFaulted":false}}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us the JSON data printed by `console.log(response);`?

Comment: Your HTML table appears to have 4 columns (first one is for a checkbox with no label in a div), whereas your DataTables definition is only expecting 3 columns - that may also cause a problem.

Comment: @andrewjames I have added the json result from console.log(data)

Comment: Please do not provide text as a screenshot - instead, you can provide the actual text (formatted, as needed). We can't copy/paste the data from a screenshot. Also, in this specific case, we would need to see the actual raw JSON data - not a re-structured representation.

Comment: @andrewjames I am unable to copy the console.log(response) from the browser.

Comment: The JSON is part of the POST response. You can see the response details in the console "network" tab.

Comment: Having said that, from what I could briefly see, your JSON data's row arrays appear to be in your JSON response at `data.result`. So, to access it you would need to change `data: response,` to `data: response.data.result,`. But we would need access to the JSON text to be sure. After that, I guess there may be a new/different error in the browser's console.

Comment: Check This Link :-    https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable

Comment: @andrewjames I have added the json data.

Comment: Sorry - that latest edit does not show valid JSON data. But, in case it helps, you can try that change I mentioned above.

Comment: @andrewjames please refer to latest.

Comment: @andrewjames response.data.result works

Comment: Yes - that was the JSON, thank you. Once we can see the JSON, the problem is clear and the fix is straightforward. Do you now see new errors, or do you now see your data OK?

Comment: @andrewjames I see my data OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data has the following overall structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {...},
      {...},
      {...},
      ...
      {...}
    ],
    "id": 1601,
    "exception": null,
    ...
    "isFaulted": false
  }
}
```

The `"result": [ ]` array is where you see the data needed to populate the table. Each `{...}` object in that array represents one row of table data.

Therefore you have to point DataTables at that array, so it knows where, inside your JSON, to look for the data it will display. DataTables will automtically handle iteration over each item in that array.

This is why you needed to change this:

```
data: response,
```

to this:

```
data: response.data.result,
```

in your DataTable definition. Here, `response` is the name of the variable containing the overall response JSON. And `data.result` is the specific location inside that JSON where your table data is stored.